# Using Nikon D5300 Live View with a Amscope microscope lens

Tags: nikon, live-view, manual-mode, microscopy

I have read that Live View on Nikon cameras doesn't work with certain lens but searching through the user manual there is no mention of this. Our research lab is trying to use Live View with Nikon D5300 and the Amscope Microscope lens [(CA-CAN-NIK-SLR)](http://www.amscope.com/canon-nikon-and-olumpus-slr-dslr-camera-adapter-for-microscopes.html). I can only take pictures in manual mode because camera info-message says it is the only mode allowed for non-CPU lenses. Then , when I try to switch it into Live View it gives us the error message: "Cannot start live view at current settings or under current conditions."   Is there a way to override this and allow Live Mode or would we have to get a different microscope lens with particular specifications? I am a beginner with cameras so even relevant basic information would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The camera would not go into live view mode or playback mode because the usb cord was plugged into its side. It has nothing to do with the microscope lens which only requires that the camera be in manual (M) mode to shoot photos.